# Change styles when ng-repeat updates after push AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of elements and I need to stylish the last item after pushing a new element.

This is my array:

```
$scope.items = [{id: 1, name: "Jhon Doe"}, {id:2, name: "Susane"}];
```

Array is binding to ng-repeat in my view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
    <div id="item-{{ $index }}">
         {{ item.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

When array is updated, I need to apply some styling to the last item, the one added dynamically, I'm using jQuery:

```
$scope.add = function(){
   var item = { id:10, name: 'Martha' };
   $scope.items.push(item);

   jQuery('#item-' + ($scope.items.length - 1) ).css('background', 'red');
}
```

But it doesn't work, because I think DOM is not yet updated when pushing. I've tried to use `$scope.watchCollection` but It doesn't work.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get out of the jQuery way of thinking (DOM first) and get into the angular way of thinking... updating data models and let angular manage the DOM.

Use the `$last` property created in child scopes of `ng-repeat` the same way `$index` is. You shouldn't need element ID's but rarely in angular

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
  <div ng-class="{'red-class': $last}">
     {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

I would suggest you completely remove jQuery from project unless you have a very specific plugin need for it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what about effects animations or effects applied with jQuery UI?. What I need is to apply a "highlight effect" when the new element is pushed into array.

Comment: need to read up on how ngAnimate works . Use css to do animations . 'ng-repeat` will add classes also that can use animations css

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right, I need to start to think in "angularjs" way and left behind other technologies like jQuery. Question marked as solved.